# Arcpy: Summary Statistics for Mean and non-statistic value?

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to write a script where I can calculate the average, minimum, and maximum of three separate fields. I can begin to envision, and having looked for a while through other SO posts, I know it is possible to do a dictionary or a search cursor, but given that I'm still new to python I thought that if possible calling the Summary Statistics tool would be easier.

However, it seems that one can only output the desired statistic and has no control over including in the output the other fields/rows that go along with it, as an example, in a .dbf with an id field, a state_name field, and a death rate field, the script will find the highest death rate and output that with the id, but not with the state_name. Is it possible to code this somehow in arcpy?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Statistics_analysis(in_table, out_table, statistics_fields;statistics_fields..., case_field;case_field...})
```

Calculates summary statistics for field(s) in a table.

If you need to control which rows are input, you can makes selections (like w/arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()) prior to calculating stats.